# AWS Lambda function upgrade from NodeJs version 6.10 to 8.10 version

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

AWS lambda function node js version 6.10 reached end of the life now we have to upgrade the all functions with 8.10 version.how to upgrade the version and in RunTime 8.10 version is available can we choose the 8.10 version from RunTime it will upgrade the version...?

i am not aware of this before could you please suggest how to upgrade the node js version in AWS lambda function

Requirement is upgrade the lambda functions to latest version i.e from 6.10 to 8.10.

Comment: could you please let me know the steps because 8.10 version is there in RUNTIME so i want to go with 8.10.how to upgrade it to latest version if it is not available in RUNTIME also...?

Answer (score 1):

1.From the AWS console go to Lambda service

2. Click on your function, you should see an option to choose the runtime in the UI
   [image]
3. Select Node.js 8.10

in case you're using serverless framework, you can also set it from serverless.yaml file

Comment: than you for your response kindly please help me on this i can able to see the 8.10 version in RunTime my doubt is if we choose the 8.10 version the code will updated it will work without changing anything..?

Comment: @Srk yup, your code will then be running on NodeJS 8.10 and you should be able to make use of new language features like async/await