# how to upgrade the node version of an aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In AWS I have a lambda function that is on node version 10, but I want to update its `run time version` - which command do I run to make this happen e.g. wanting to update `runtime` to version 12? I am aware there is already a post at [AWS Lambda function upgrade from NodeJs version 6.10 to 8.10 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56056210/aws-lambda-function-upgrade-from-nodejs-version-6-10-to-8-10-version), but I would **like to know how to do this via a command and not the console**.

Comment: if the answer helped you can you accept it as answer so that it helps others in the future :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In console:

- Go to your function
- Go to the "Code" tab
- **Scroll down** to "Runtime settings"
- Click "Edit"

Now you can select a later Node.js version

Comment: I must be going crazy, where is that ???

Comment: @fattie Search for "runtime settings". It was kinda hidden underneath the code tab.

Comment: Might be obvious but make sure you select the region where your lambda functions are, and then click on the function which you want to edit.

Answer (score 7):

if you want to update lambda  with a specific node run time version i think this should help, this uses aws cli **( use updated version of aws cli)**

```
   aws lambda update-function-configuration \
    --function-name  my-function \
    ----runtime nodejs10.x
```

see [API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-configuration.html) for more

Comment: but in my case the function already exists, I do not want to create a new one

Comment: I have updated my answer and api docs link too :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, no one going to scroll the page, so it's hidden.

[image: runtime version settings for AWS lambda]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use https://github.com/fusebit/everynode project to run any version of Node.js in AWS Lambda, not just the set natively supported by AWS.